# Best way to run a Nextcloud server on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nextcloud

so I'm thinking about running a Nextcloud server on GCP BUT it won't be accessed much, maybe in total half an hour a day by 3 users (not really at the same time much). What GCP product should I use to run it on since it will be idle a lot of times...?

Cheers,
Thibault

EDIT: the reason why I'm asking is because I want to keep the cost very low and I feel like since it's idle a lot of the time, there might be a specific GCP product/service to pick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using one of the micro-bursting shared-core Compute Engine virtual machines. These share a CPU core with other VMs on the same physical server, so they're very inexpensive. In the case of the `f1-micro` variant, Google actually lets you keep one on (and active) at all times without even charging you for it.

For instantaneous performance, Google also allows the shared-core VMs to temporarily use up to a full core during short periods of high load. That should help with access and write speed.

For periods of sustained load, you could try setting up something that uses Compute Engine's preemptible nodes. These are usually less than half the price of regular VMs, with the caveat that they can't last more than 24 hours at a time and they might get terminated at any minute to free up supply for regular VMs. So the shared-core VM(s) would provide high availability and adequate performance for light or brief loads, and you could spin up additional preemptible servers to help with heavy lifting when necessary.

In terms of storage value, you'd probably be best off keeping most of your data on HDD-backed persistent disk(s), then taking some load off of it and speeding up access to commonly used files with RAM or SSD-backed caching at the OS level.

If there are large datasets that you don't use very often but still need occasional access to, you might be able to save some money as well by moving them into Nearline or Coldline Cloud Storage and setting them up on your server through a `FUSE` mount.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest using [Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/) as mentioned in other comments. Running Nextcloud on GCP for almost a year I found the `f1-micro` often short on memory even in idle states. I am running Nextcloud in Docker using fpm-alpine image plus nginx, redis, mysql and encryption. So use at least the `g1-small`. The shared CPU tiers have disadvantage if you plan to store a lot of pictures, every first load of picture through Web UI and Nextcloud App will trigger thumbnail generation what is CPU heavy operation and will cause unresponsiveness of Nextcloud on low CPU instances. Opening a folder with lots of pictures will make Nextcloud WebUI unresponsive for everyone (and Nextcloud app will give you errors) until the thumbnails are generated.

If you pick the N1 series Standard tier, I recommend to use [Committed use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts)
If you go for `n1-standard-1` and 3-year commitment the price is almost as the `g1-small` (could depend on region).
For N1 series you will also get [Sustained use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#sustained_use) even if you don't commit.

For your small amount of users I don't recommend the use of Cloud SQL Instances. You won't utilize the available resources even on the smallest tier.

As for the HDD, I am using standard persistent disk, which is quite cheap already.

Also pick your region carefully, some are cheaper than others.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate choice, for your use case, would be to host it on a [Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/).

As for the service being often idle, unfortunately there's no official GCP solution for it, since you're still charged for any running GCE instance as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#instanceuptime).

The only way for it to stop charging you, is to stop the VM, but it will still charge you for the disk until you delete it. Therefore pricing depends on the [machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#pricing) and the [disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#disk) you choose for the instance.

Nonetheless, a workaround that may perhaps help you is to use an external third-party software, such as the [automated scheduling tool](https://www.parkmycloud.com/free-trial/?utm_campaign=prospects&utm_content=free-trial&utm_medium=social&utm_source=quora) that can turn the VM on or off depending on its usage; but this would indeed mean you'd have to wait for the instance to start up before being able to use it.